# How can I remove the last two characters of a specific element in my list?

Tags: python, list

So I have these text files that contains metadata, and I made this code that prints each line of it (of the first metadata file) :

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\basse\\Pictures\\OneM\\metadata\\P5JS metadata\\Metadata'

with open(path + '1.txt') as file:
    lines = []
    for line in file:
        lines.append(line)


print(lines[0], end ="")
print(lines[1], end ="")
print(lines[2], end ="")
print(lines[3], end ="")
print(lines[4], end ="")
```

Now the problem is that the fourth and fifth line looks like this in my metadata file

```
1.0
4.0
```

So what happens when I print it is that I get :

```
Blue sky
Blue Ice
Rounded Rectangle
1.0
4.0
```

How can I remove the last two character (So the .0) of these one ?

Comment: Reminds me of [XY Problem Example 1](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this,

```
with open(path + '1.txt') as file:
    lines = []
    for line in file:
        lines.append(line. replace(".0", ""))

print(lines[0], end ="")
print(lines[1], end ="")
print(lines[2], end ="")
print(lines[3], end ="")
print(lines[4], end ="")
```

Or you can just do this

```
with open(path + '1.txt') as file:
    lines = []
    for line in file:
        lines.append(line)

print(lines[0], end ="")
print(lines[1], end ="")
print(lines[2], end ="")
print(lines[3].replace(".0", ""), end ="")
print(lines[4].replace(".0", ""), end ="")
```

Comment: I tried it but I get an error 
"invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.0\n'"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex replacement to strip off trailing `.0`:

```py
with open(path + '1.txt') as file:
    lines = []
    for line in file:
        lines.append(re.sub(r'\.\d+$', '', line))
```

The above will actually strip any decimal component.  If you really want to target only trailing `.0`, then use `\.0$`.